# Converting datetime to INT in order to sum hours and minutes in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to sum two columns, both of which are of datatype `DateTime` which I have already converted to `varchar`.

The problem I'm having right now is that when I try to cast as an int and then `SUM` both columns I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '00:00:00' to data type int

Code:

```
CONVERT(varchar(8), dbo.AlteracoesSaldos.SaldoInicial, 108) AS Time1, CONVERT(varchar(8), dbo.alteracoessaldos.SaldoPeriodo, 108) AS Time2
```

[image]

I have tried this query as follows:

```
SUM(CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), dbo.AlteracoesSaldos.SaldoInicial, 108) AS int) 
    + CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), dbo.alteracoessaldos.SaldoPeriodo, 108) AS int)) AS Soma
```

but I get the error I mentioned at the top of the post.

My goal is to sum the hours and minutes as in:

```
16:33 + 18:14 = 34:47
```

Thanks!

Comment: Convert the values to seconds and add those. Don't try to aggregate times; it doesn't work.

Comment: Side note [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/), stick to aliasing your objects and qualifying your column names with those

Comment: Why did you convert to char? And why use `datetime` if you really wanted a *duration*? Both are wrong and will result in unexpected results if you store a duration of more than 1 month: January has 31 days, but February back in 0001? I don't know. The sum can easily end up adding or subtracting days. And strings are definitely not integers, so they can't be added.

Comment: In any case, you can sum the *legacy datetime* values but that's just a quirk that will lead into the problems I mentioned. You could use `Sum(SaldoInicial)` *but* the results would be unreliable. There wouldn't be any issues for durations up to 31 days. For that reason, the newer `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset` and `time` types don't allow addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the expected result "34:47" is not a correct time format, you will have to go with Larnus idea to convert the values to seconds. Furthermore the result will be varchar / char. Following an example how to achieve the expected result:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
x time, y time
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES('16:33:15.000', '18:14:00.000')

SELECT *
      ,CONCAT((DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00.000', x)+DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00.000', y))/(60*60)
             ,':'
             ,((DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00.000', x)+DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00.000', y))%(60*60))/60
             ,':'
             ,((DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00.000', x)+DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00.000', y))%(60*60))%60
             ) TotalTime
  FROM @t
```

Comment: I have used your solution and it seems to work fine although there is a quirk.

Considering I want to use only HH:MM and not include seconds, i have used your first 2 concatenated lines which do exactly what i want, but the minutes values shows a negative symbol behind the minute. example: -28:-11, -13:-13. besides that it it exactly what i need.

Comment: Please provide the sample value for which the result is negative.

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment. I was doing something wrong. Your solution works as intended. Thank your for your collaboration!

Answer (score -2):

### Below may help you but it is in mysql

the view `detail_view` which contents the duration as time:

```
+----------+
| mytime |
+----------+
| 00:02:07 |
| 00:05:45 |
| 00:01:15 |
| 00:13:09 |
| 00:35:45 |
| 00:11:29 |
| 00:03:54 |
| 00:01:27 |
| 00:10:53 |
+----------+

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(SECOND(mytime))) FROM detail_view;

+----------------------------------+
| SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(SECOND(mytime))) |
+----------------------------------+
| 00:04:44 |
+----------------------------------+
```

For further details, refer [this](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,194872,194872)

Comment: Answering in a different dialect to the one the OP is asking in isn't helpful. It's almost like giving as answer written in C to a question asking about C++. `SEC_TO_TIME` doesn't exist in T-SQL, so this won't work in the dialect.